# MySQL query for summing values in another table

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have got a couple of tables with a parent child relationship. I want to apply a sum function to one column of child table and return it with all data of parent table for example.

```
Parent_table
ID, Date, Title

Child_table
ID, another_id, column_to_sum
//(ID is foreign key pointing to Parent_table)

Sample Data in Parent_table
1, 22-11-2010 00:00:00 , 'Some Title'
2, 13-11-2010 00:00:00 , 'Some Title 2'

Sample Data in Child_table
1, 1, 10
1, 2, 11
1, 8, 3
2, 5, 11
2, 8, 6
```

Output of the query should return all columns in `parent_table` with an additional column, that is, summing the values of `column_to_sum` in `Child_table` for each item in parent_table matched by ID.

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SELECT p.ID,
      p.Date,
      p.Title,
      SUM(c.column_to_sum) Total
    FROM Parent_Table p LEFT JOIN
       Child_Table c ON p.ID = c.ID
    GROUP BY p.ID
```

Comment: Firstly, try to format the code correctly. use ht ecode burron 010101. Also, what about your **GROUP BY**?

Comment: This will give the error: Column 'Parent_Table.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. You'll have to add p.Date and p.Table to the GROUP BY for this query to work, or aggregate the fields like for ex. MIN(p.Date). It is inefficient to GROUP BY or aggregate each field.

Answer (score 3):

This does not exactly answer the question, but might help someone since this was my solution. (I know it's missing the JOIN) And have no idea about the efficiency of this solution on a large DB.

```
SELECT 
    Parent_table.*,
        (SELECT 
            SUM(Child_table.column_to_sum) 
        FROM Child_table 
        WHERE Child_table.id = Parent_table.id)
FROM Parent_table
```

Answer (score 2):

This is off the top of my head, but how about

```
SELET p.ID,
  p.Date,
  p.Title,
  SUM(c.column_to_sum) Total
FROM Parent_Table p INNER JOIN
   Child_Table c ON p.ID = c.ID
GROUP BY p.ID,
      p.Date,
      p.Title
```

Comment: you should only group by the one column, then use order by if you want it sorted differently `GROUP BY p.ID ORDER BY p.Date, p.Title`